# Automatic ip switching

Tags: 12.04, networking

I have two network connections. Two of them are not stable. These connections go down at least once a day. So is it possible to switch the connection (gateway) automatically to another if one goes down? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you can just set both nic cards up, one as a primary and one as a secondary. In the event your primary goes down. You can then fall back on the secondary. I prefer static IP address but you should be able to use dhcp as well. Hope this helps

Example for static.

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static 
address 192.168.2.100 
netmask 255.255.255.0 
network 192.168.2.0 
broadcast 192.168.2.255 
gateway 192.168.2.1

auto eth1 
iface eth1 inet static 
address 192.168.2.99 
netmask 255.255.255.0 
network 192.168.2.0 
broadcast 192.168.2.255